# Render Partial view as modal popup with Jquery Datatable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, datatables

Can anybody have sample code/reference to Display JQuery Datatable inside modal popup using partial view in MVC 4 Razor view

Please give me some code or sample application

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried to take simple modal and add datatable into it for test?

Comment: Yes -  have tried that is also same behaviour